# Why is Nginx displaying a "502 Bad Gateway Error"?

Tags: nginx, python, django

I'm trying to create a PyPI  (Python) package repository on a Debian 8 server running Nginx 1.6.2.  I want to make all the files in a particular directory tree available for downloading to my other servers via HTTP.  My Python packages are all kept in the /var/www/packages directory:

```
/var/www/packages
/var/www/packages/Django-1.8.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
/var/www/packages/simple
/var/www/packages/simple/index.html
/var/www/packages/simple/django
/var/www/packages/simple/django/Django-1.8.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl -> ../../Django-1.8.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

If I try to read my packages directory from another server using curl, I get the following error:

```
$ curl -I http://example.com/packages/simple/django/Django-1.8.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
$ HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
```

If I just try to display the Nginx default home page, I'm getting the same error:

```
502 Bad Gateway
```

The /var/log/nginx/error.log file shows this error in either case:

```
2019/02/06 00:53:52 [alert] 3736#0: 768 worker_connections are not enough
2019/02/06 00:53:52 [error] 3736#0: *765 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:80/", host: "example.com:80"
```

Here is my Nginx configuration file:

```
upstream pypi {
  server            127.0.0.1   fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  server_name       example.com;
  root          /var/www/packages;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header    Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass      http://pypi;          # <- Error here
  }
}
```

As I understand it, this error means that Nginx, which is acting as a proxy, is trying to relay information from another server but has received a bad response from that server.  But in this situation, I'm merely trying to make a directory tree on the proxy server available via HTTP so, strictly speaking, there is no other server.

To troubleshoot the problem, I commented out the root directive and the entire location block.  When I did this, the 502 error went away and I could at least see the default Nginx home page. Then I began uncommenting each directive each directive in the location block, one at a time.  By doing this, I found that I could continue to see the Nginx page if I uncommented the entire location block except for the proxy_pass directive.  That proxy_pass line is what's causing the problem.  What does proxy_pass have to be set to in a situation like this?  And do I set root to /var/www/packages since that's the root directory for my packages?

Comment: I read that question and it doesn't help because the author is discussing a nodejs site whereas I'm only trying to serve files from a directory.  Also, I'm essentially doing what the people who replied to his question suggested he do and it's not working.  That's why I posted this question.

Comment: I've resolved this issue.  The problem was that I was making my Nginx config  harder than it needed to be.  Once I looked at the problem as of one of setting up my server as an Nginx file server, the solution was simple.  I didn't need all of those proxy_* directives.  All I needed was a server block with listen, root, server_name, and location directives and my server worked as desired.